# How to access templates in Python?

Tags: python, templates

Sometimes, for a program with a lot of data, it is common to place the data in an external file. An example is a script that produces an HTML report, using an external file to hold a template.

In Java, the most recommended way to retrieve a resource of the program is to use `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource()` or `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()` for a stream.

The advantage is that this is independent of the file system. Also, it works whether the classes are in the file system or the application is distributed as a Jar file.

How do you achieve the same in Python ? What if you're using [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) or [Freeze](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Freeze) to generate a stand-alone running app, as seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331377/how-to-pack-python-libs-im-using-so-i-can-distribute-them-with-my-app-and-have-a) ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `os.path.dirname(__file__)` to get the directory of the current module.  Then use the [path manipulation](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) functions (specifically, os.path.join) and [file input/output](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) to open a file under the current module.

Answer (score 1):

What Daniel said. :-)  Also, py2exe can be told to include external files (this is often used for images etc).