# Loading bundled python framework dependencies using only python

Tags: python

I've come across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331377/) but I don't like the solution that is presented. Shell scripting is operating system dependent.

Is there a python solution to this problem?

I'm not looking for python to machine code compilers, just a way to modify the include paths with python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, python follows the paths in sys.path when trying to resolve library dependencies. `sys.path` is a list, and it is searched in order. If your application modified `sys.path` on load to put its own library paths at the front, this should do the trick.

This section from the python docs has a good explanation of how python finds its dependencies: https://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement.

Comment: Dammit Jim! Yes, I do mean sys.paths. First I wrote sys.paths. Then I edited it to sys.modules. Now back to sys.paths. Don't mind me... just being silly this morning it seems. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2):

Well, as far as I know there are many different pieces of advice on how to do it.

Here are 2 approaches that may help you distribute your app

I/

. include all dependencies in my project directory structure

. manipulate the sys.path to make sure that the app is always looking in my dir structure before looking into the system available modules

(Disclaimer: this solution might not work if C libs are involved)

II/

Another approach is using a tool like [EasyInstall and eggs](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/PythonEggs). This solution might be a bit more complex, but it will offer you a lot of freedom on how to configure your app and its dependencies (plus it will work with C dependencies).

./alex

Comment: I'm going to have to look into using eggs.